# VBA nested IF / ElseIF help conditional hyperlink creation

Tags: excel, vba, nested

Hoping someone can help – I expect there is something very simple that I am doing wrong.

The situation is this:

- I have a table with variable rows (month to month)
- Four columns where the one I am trying to place the formula in (CaseLink) is blank

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9EJY.png)

- The column ‘System’ has one of three values; CSv1, CSv2, PIA
- The Case # column will have numbers – no repetition or consistency
- The CaseLink column is where I am having the issue – I am trying to insert one of three hyperlinks to include the value in the Case # column. The link target is based on the value in the System column

Previously I only had two variables in the System column and was able to solve for with a simple IF statement as it was either true or false. Now with a third variable, I am having difficulties with the If / ElseIF format. Here is what I have tried:

Original if statement that works:

```
    
       Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]=""CSv1"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open. cloudav.com/servicedeliverdo.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.topcloudav.com/ha2servicedeliverdo.aspx?conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]))"
    
    Range("D3").Select
```

Option 1: (this returns an error: Sub or Function not defined on Concatenate)

```
       Range("C2").Select
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CSv1" Then Hyperlink (CONCATENATE("https://open.cloudav.com/servicedo.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="),RC[-1]),RC[-1]))

ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CSv2" Then Hyperlink (CONCATENATE("https://open.cloudav.com/topservicedo.aspx?conv="),RC[-1]),RC[-1]))

ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "PIA" Then Hyperlink (CONCATENATE("https://dev.devroot.net/browse/PIA-"),RC[-1]),RC[-1]))
    
End If

    Range("D3").Select
```

Option 2: (this returns an error indicating ElseIF is undefined

```
       Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "IF(RC([-2])) = ""CSv1"" Then Hyperlink (CONCATENATE(""https://open.cloudav.com/servicedo.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="", RC[-1]), RC[-1])))"

elseif_
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "IF(RC([-2]) = ""CSv2"" then Hyperlink (CONCATENATE(""https://open.cloudav.com/topservicedo.aspx?conv="", RC[-1]), RC[-1])))"

elseif_
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "IF(RC([-2]))= ""PIA"" Then"
        Hyperlink (concatenate("https://dev.devroot.net/browse/PIA-", (RC([-1])), (RC([-1]))))
    
End If

    Range("D3").Select
```

I have also tried ActiveCell.Offset rather than ActiveCell.Formula with similar failure results

Any thoughts?

Comment: These all appear to be formatting errors. There is a structure and a syntax that needs to be followed for any code to work.

Comment: Post an entire procedure so we can see what you are doing. Try to clean it up a bit. Indent properly and make sure you only have one command per line.

Comment: Line continuations `_` require a space before them.  Your layout and syntax is all off - please read up a bit on how to format `If` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of thing that could be improve in your code:

- Use variable instead of hard code
- do not select
- Indent better

I tried to replicate what you were doing,

```
Sub hyperlink()

Dim firstcellrow As Long       ' First row where your code acts
Dim systemcellcollumn As Long  ' Column w the system entries
Dim linkcollumn As Long        ' Column where you want to link stuff

firstcellrow = 1       ' In my case
systemcellcollumn = 2  'From your image
linkcollumn = 4        'From your image

Dim activecellrow As Long ' Its a long name but thats actualy just a counter
Dim system As String      ' Not needed if u use cell.text directly into select case

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 2 ' 0 to whatever you want
activecellrow = firstcellrow + i

system = Worksheets("test").Cells(activecellrow, systemcellcollumn).Text ' Not necessary, see comment under "Select Case"
Select Case system 
' or Select Case Worksheets("test").Cells(activecellrow, systemcellcollumn).Text 
    Case "CSv1"
         Cells(activecellrow, linkcollumn).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""CSv1"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open. cloudav.com/servicedeliverdo.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.topcloudav.com/ha2servicedeliverdo.aspx?conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]))"
    Case "CSv2"
        'etc 
    Case "PIA"
    'etc
End Select
Next

End Sub
```

This code may not be perfect but is already more general and works

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the comments - I am not a professional coder - This is something I am trying to get done by learning from everyone else. If this is not a forum where someone can go to ask for help without getting blasted for style, I apologize for wasting your time.

I did figure out a simple method of getting this done on my own in a single nested IF statement:

```
Range("C2").Select
   
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]=""CSv1"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.cloudav.com/deliverdo.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]),IF(RC[-2]=""CSv2"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.cloudav.com/topdeliverdo.aspx?conv="",RC[-1]),RC[-1]),IF(RC[-2]=""PIA"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://dev.devroot.net/browse/PIA-"",RC[-1]),RC[-1]))))"
    Range("A2").Select
```

Comment: Nobody's being mean here, as you're new, you just don't know about how to present or write in order to make it easier for us to help you back. It's the "help me help you" mindset as well as "help futur you": you can read the answer on that code review, it covers general "problems" new coders (as i was and still am sometime) have. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/246013/excel-data-import-and-manipulation